# Win32 in C++ displays in Chinese ... what did i do wrong?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, win32gui

I am new to win32 and C++  , i just started learning 
followed  a tutorial online and wrote this code :

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR) "Yes, I remember Adlestrop", (LPCWSTR) "A minimal windows program", MB_OK);
return 0;
}
```

But when in compiled and run the code the,in the   message box the text were sort of Chinese ...
I know that if i don mention proper types the the output  might be binary or ASCCI or hex .... But first time it turned out be Chinese ..
Can any one tell me what I did wrong ? ?

Comment: Don't cast things to solve type errors. A narrow string is not a wide string. Pretending it is, as you can see, doesn't work at all.

Comment: Well, wide strings take two bytes per character. Your narrow strings are one byte per character. Guess what happens when you put two of your characters' binary together and interpret it as a wide character. CJK characters are numerous (in the tens of thousands at least) and in that range.

Comment: Ok ... now i got your point ! .. Thank You Sir ..from next time i will keep that in mind !

Comment: You lied to the compiler. Your cast simply suppresses type safety. In effect you are telling the compiler that you know better than it does.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are calling Unicode functions but passing ASCII text in.

This cast is **wrong:**

```
(LPCWSTR) "Yes, I remember Adlestrop"
```

Instead, use the `L` prefix, and don't cast:

```
L"Yes, I remember Adlestrop"
```

### Explanation

Prefixing a string literal with `L` means that the literal will be encoded with UTF-16<sup>1</sup> and have elements of type `wchar_t` instead of `char`.  Win32 expects UTF-16, unless you `#undef UNICODE` which is generally a bad idea.

### The `TEXT()` macro

You might see code which uses the `TEXT()` macro.

```
TEXT("Yes, I remember Adlestrop")
```

This is an old way of doing things to retain compatibility with code written before Unicode was available.  Unless you are maintaining a legacy application, you should avoid the `TEXT()` macro, and leave `UNICODE` defined.  `UNICODE` is defined by default in recent versions of Visual Studio so there is usually no need to define it yourself.

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup>: On Windows.

Comment: ye that Solve The Problem  Thanks man ... ( I didn't know wrong type casting would result in Chinese Characters ..I THOUGHT THAT WAS JUST A FIGURE OF SPEECH OF Some kind  )

Comment: Casting is "disabling the safeties" so to speak... it makes the code compile, but it makes it your responsibility to ensure that the code is correct.

Comment: Since the OP's code is using the **generic** flavor of `MessageBox()`, it should use the `TEXT()` macro to match: `MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Yes, I remember Adlestrop"), TEXT("A minimal windows program"), MB_OK);`.  Use the `L` specifier only if you call `MessageBoxW()` directly: `MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Yes, I remember Adlestrop", L"A minimal windows program", MB_OK);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Actually, the `TEXT()` macro is only useful for legacy applications where you might compile with `UNICODE` not defined.  It is not useful for modern development.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: the exact same claim applies to the `MessageBox()` , which is `TCHAR`-based, as it maps to either `MessageBoxW()` or `MessageBoxA()` depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined or not, just like the `TEXT()` macro (and `TCHAR` data type) maps to `wchar_t` or `char` depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined. Modern development is not supposed to be using `TCHAR` and `TCHAR`-based APIs at all anymore. So a modern app should be using `MessageBoxW()` directly, not `MessageBox()` anymore.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: If you are going to use a `TCHAR`-based API, you better use `TCHAR`-based data to go with it, and that is where `TEXT()` comes into play.